# why sparkcontext stopped?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I configured spark on hadoop. spark is 1.5.2 and hadoop is 2.7.2, and I checked from jps, port 8080(hadoop) and port 8088(spark) that spark and hadoop were working well. I accessed "spark-shell --master yarn-client". Next, I created sparkcontext, and The following logs appeared. I don't know at all why this log showed. What does "stopped SparkContext" mean? I just made sparkcontext. How could sparkcontext have stopped? Didn't sparkcontext start?

Could you give me any idea?

```
scala> val lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:104)
    at
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:2063)
    at
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultMinPartitions(SparkContext.scala:2076)
    at
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile$default$2(SparkContext.scala:825)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:21)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at <init>(<console>:40)
    at .<init>(<console>:44)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at
scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
    at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

sometimes I got a error, when I turned on the shell. but If I turned it on again ,this error went away. Actually above case when I turned on the shell this log didn't exist, so I didn't mention that. These logs is following

```
rg.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might
have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:123)
    at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:63)
    at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:523)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:20)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
'
```

Comment: which scala version are you using?

Comment: I'm using scala 2.10.6.

Comment: You're not supposed to initialize your own `SparkContext` when using the shell: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when initializing the shell?

Comment: Above case, there weren't any error when initializing the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error happen because of yarn configure. when I execute spark-shell without "--master yarn-client", spark-shell working well. I think should rewrite .xml files.